# Forecasting by Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Consider this time series as your signal:

x=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2]

by applying DFT (discrete Fourier transform), we could find frequencies and their amplitudes. Thus, we could reconstruct our signal by using of these factors.

here is my question. If we use this reconstructed signal, what would be the next element of our time series? will it be 3? or 1?

Comment: You can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_prediction) and then see if more complex approaches are merited.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 No, I just want to deepen my understanding from DFT.